# py calculate cosine similarities between columns in a matrix (taking in account only shared rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the pairwise cosine similarities between columns in matrix (taking in account only shared rows).
In the photo bellow there is an example with the formula for calculating the similarity between 2 columns.

I am using py and store the matrix in pandas Dataframe...

I saw the `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine()` but this function taking in account the non-common rows in the denominator(I need that the norm of the vectors will calculated only with the shared rows)
Thanks in advance :)

[similarities matrix photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0unt.png)

Comment: Do you have any attempt to show?

Comment: You need to share an initial dataframe and the desired output dataframe